# What is the meaning of "to have five or more"?

Tags: meaning

There was a confusing question in my reading test.

This is the sentence in the passage:

> "All starfish have at least 5 arms, but some have more"

Is the following statement true?

> "All starfish have 5 or more arms"

My class was confused by the word "or". Some people think the statement can be re-written as:

> "All starfish have 5 arms or All starfish have more than 5 arms"

Which then makes the statement false.

So I want to ask: as a native speaker, what does this sentence really mean to you?

Comment: The statement cannot be written as described.  “five or more” acts as a single quantifier meaning “at least 5”.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I want to sorry if I ask inappropriately. Are you a native speaker?

Comment: All starfish have (5 or more) arms. This is a classic semantics problem in logic. If "my coffee tastes good with cream" is true, and "my coffee tastes good with motor oil" is false, sentential calculus states that "my coffee tastes good with milk or motor oil" is true. In English, it's not, because the *or* binds within the prepositional phrase.

Comment: @jimm101 So what is your conclusion? The statement true or false? I'm still not clear :(

Comment: @jimm101 'Or' certainly has different interpretations, with 'inclusive or' and 'exclusive r' contrasting in logic. But 'five or more' occurring before a noun group only ever has one interpretation, as Jim implies above.

Comment: Just to be awkward: some starfish have arguably lost arms to predators.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thanks a lot. By the way, it also wrote that "many kinds of starfish can regrow arms that are bitten off by predators". Did you read the passage before?

Comment: No, but I've seen a lot of Natural History programmes.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth haha. so It's a randomly coincident

Comment: Out of interest the phrases "N or less" and "N or fewer" also exist meaning "no more than N". For example "Most people in this company have worked here for 5 years or less"

Comment: I am a native BrE speaker and, neglecting logic problems and predated starfish, normally _5 or more_ has exactly the same meaning as _at least 5_. The people in your class could write the sentence "_All starfish have at least 5 arms but some have more_". But the version you quoted contains a contradiction, _All_ is inclusive so you are saying **every** starfish has both 5 arms and at the same time more than 5 arms.

Comment: @PeterJennings Thank you. The statement is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement "All starfish have 5 or more arms" is correct.
But it's better to use "**at least 5**" (as discussed in the comments), as it already means *5 or more.*

Comment: oke. but it's the test :))